# Django all-auth remove asking password twice in signup form

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I wanted to remove asking password twice from the django all-auth signup page. According to its manual [here](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html), i added the following to my settings

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Here is the complete configuration that i have used for all auth

```
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 3
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 10
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
LOGIN_URL = "/auth/login"
```

Is there some conflicting configuration that i need to know of or am i settings it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This question was posted the 10th of July. The setting was renamed (in a backwards compatible manner though). The version where `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE` became available was 0.26.0. So, likely you are using an older version where this setting is still named `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION`.

Comment: I'm using v0.47.0 and this still isn't working. It's never worked for me, having used both those parameters to False.